# Google Analytics match root page with query params

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need, in my funnel description, to filter out the root page.

Someone before me wrote `/$` which should be fine, except if the user arrives to some URL like `https://example.com/?campaign_utm=xxx`: this won't be taken in account, will it?

How can I make sure this is also taken in account. This must be something pretty common, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Google Analytics will strip special query parameters, like utm_campaign and other UTM parameters. If you would like to filter your root page, possibly containing any parameters, you can modify your regex to accept end of string or `?` character:

```
\/(\?|$)
```

More precisely, to catch your root, it should also contain beginning of string:

```
^\/(\?|$)
```